# Multiple isloated elasticsearch cluster with single docker-compose file

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I want to create 2 elasticsearch cluster in single docker-compose file, so that I can test few changes only on new es cluster,

My docker-compose file is look like this

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  elasticsearch-master:
    image: elasticsearch:6.6.0
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    mem_limit: '2048M'

  new-elasticsearch-master:
    image: elasticsearch:6.6.0
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9400:9200"
    mem_limit: '2048M'

  search:
    image: search:latest
    entrypoint: java -Delasticsearch.host=elasticsearch-master -DnewElasticsearch.host=new-elasticsearch-master -DnewElasticsearch.port=9400 -jar app.jar
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch-master
      - new-elasticsearch-master
    mem_limit: '500M'
volumes:
  esdata1:
  esdata2:
```

I have 1 java service where I am adding both the host with different environment variable

1. -Delasticsearch.host=elasticsearch-master
2. -DnewElasticsearch.host=new-elasticsearch-master

But when I run code from java search service as follow

```
new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://elasticsearch-master:9200/_cat/indices?v",String.class)
```

This gives me correct response.

---

But when I try to connect to another host on 9400.

```
new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://new-elasticsearch-master:9400/_cat/indices?v",String.class)
```

I am getting **Connection Refused** error

When I try same host with 9200 then that gives me 200 response.

```
new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://new-elasticsearch-master:9200/_cat/indices?v",String.class)
```

Can someone please tell me how can I make 2 different connection with different port as below.

1. http://elasticsearch-master:9200
2. http://new-elasticsearch-master:9400

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the expected behavior. The `ports` field in docker-compose map the ports to your localhost, which mean that the "old" Elasticsearch will be available via localhost:9200 and the "new" Elasticsearch will be available via localhost:9400.

On the other hand, docker-compose services communicate in an internal network and the service name is the hostname and the port is the original listening port.

Thus, you were able to access (internally) your old one via http://elasticsearch-master:9200 and the new one via http://new-elasticsearch-master:9200.

If you wish to use the new Elasticsearch with 9400 you need to change its [settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/modules-network.html#common-network-settings): `http.port`. You can do that like:

```
  new-elasticsearch-master:
    image: elasticsearch:6.6.0
    volumes:
      - esdata2:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - http.port=9400
    ports:
      - "9400:9400"
    mem_limit: '2048M'
```

note that you have to change the port mapping as well (because it will map your new port, 9400 to the localhost 9400).

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem and also understood the problem.